# .NET Core 2.2 Unable to reach Controller but scaffolded Login works

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[image]

I am currently unable to reach my Account Controller. I am replacing the Scaffolded Identity Login due to certain reasons.

The current path to my AccountController is Areas > Identity > Pages > Account > AccountController

Previously it would be Areas > Identity > Pages > Account > Login

This is the top of my AccountController

```
[Area("Identity")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[TypeFilter(typeof(ValidateApplicationStatusFilter), Arguments = new object[] { ApplicationGlobals.DocumentStudio })]
public class AccountController : Controller
```

In my Startup.cs I have set the loginpath as this:

```
options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
```

I have tried to put a debugger on my Login function in the AccountController but it never hits. When I login now, it shows me a different login form that seems to be the default created by .net?

Comment: What is your route configuration? Could you share it?

Comment: Could you try putting your controller in the following folder: Areas > Identity > Controllers ?

Answer (score 2):

I found out what the issue was.

In Startup.cs, I was using

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity
```

This somehow forced it to use the default login page. When I changed it to

```
services.AddIdentity
```

It worked.

Comment: The `Default` in `AddDefaultIdentity` literally refers to an internal call to `AddDefaultUI()`, which is what includes Identity UI from the RCL.